# View overlapping another view in LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout

I have a wierd problem.

I define a LinearLayout with vertical orientation.

I define an ImageView and another custom View.

if I add the custom one and then the image, all is fine and I see both of them.

if I add the image one first, I see only the image.

I try any variation of LayoutParams and nothing worked.

what I'm doing wrong here?

*Edit* - I even tried some default button to check its not my custom view that causing this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_strip));
Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
button.setText("test");
layout.addView(image, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
layout.addView(button, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 setContentView(layout);
}
```

I found a way, but its still has an issue.

I used RelativeLayout, and aligned the button to the bottom of the parent (the layout) and I set the image to be above the button.

now I see both of them, but the problem now is that the image width also shrinks

Comment: Post code.  Layout xml and your custom view code.

Answer (score 0):

How big is your image?  If its bigger than the view area, its going to push the button off screen.  If the button is first, you'll see it.  If the button is after the image, you won't.  That would be my first guess.  You could wrap the whole thing (the parent LinearLayout) in a ScrollView to see if its doing that.  If so, you'll need to clip the image somehow.

If the image is bigger than the screen size, try the following.  Create the parent LL as you have it, then create a ScrollView and add the image inside that.  Set the layout_weight of the ScrollView to 1 (or whatever), and DON'T set the layout_weight of the button.  This should force the ScrollView to take up as much space as possible, but leave room for the button, and allow you to scroll to see the image.

I don't have good code off hand for doing this in code.  I do most layout in XML (and not to pontificate, but I'd suggest the same for you ;)

Comment: I don't want to scroll to the button, I want to see them both. and if the size of the image is too big, how do I make it to auto fit it, after I add the button?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/myprogress"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Small"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"       />



<ImageView
    android:layout_height="165dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Check for the above layout of progressbar and imageview. What I wanted was to overlap the imageview over progressbar and I achieved the same by setting android:layout_marginTop="-30dp" to imageview